# Should I memoize the returned object of a custom React hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, memoization

If I used `useCallback` for the methods of my custom hook, should I also memoize the returned object? I would assume that it would not create a new object everytime since it's composed with memoized methods and primitives.

```
export const useToggle = (args: UseToggleProps) => {
    const initialState=
        args.initialState !== undefined ? args.initialState : false
    const [active, setActive] = useState(initialState)

    const toggleOff = useCallback(() => {
        setActive(false)
    }, [])

    const toggleOn = useCallback(() => {
        setActive(true)
    }, [])

    const toggle = useCallback(() => {
        setActive((active) => !active)
    }, [])

    // Should this also be memoized with useMemo?
    return {
        active,
        toggle,
        toggleOff,
        toggleOn
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to memoize the returned object unless you are passing the Object directly to function of useEffect in which case reference will fail

You don't need to add an extra layer of memoization over `useCallback` if you use it like this:

```
const Comp = () => {
   const { toggleOn, toggleOff } = useToggle();

   useEffect(() => {
      console.log('Something here')
   }, [toggleOn]);  
   return (
       <Child toggleOn={toggleOn} toggleOff={toggleOff} />
   )
}
```

However the usages like below code will need memoization of the returned object

```
const Comp = () => {
   const toggle = useToggle();

   useEffect(() => {
      console.log('Something here')
   }, [toggle]);  
   return (
       <Child toggleHandlers={toggle} />
   )
}
```

Comment: I see, I never use it as in your second example, so I won't wrap my returned object in another layer of `useCallback`. Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help :-)

Comment: Second question as I think it's related. If I chose to wrap the returned object in useMemo as such, with the only array parameter being `active`, could I omit all the useCallback?: `return useMemo( ( ) => { {
        active,
        toggle,
        toggleOff,
        toggleOn
    } } , [ active ])`

Comment: Not really, because if active changes new instances of each function is created  whcih is not what you want

Comment: OK. I thought that ultimately, the useMemo taking only `active` as a parameter would ignore the new instances. Thanks